# My object has a top and bottom in 2D curve mode but not 3D. How can I fix this?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I wanted to create a model from a .svg image in Blender. This model is going into Garry's Mod, so it must be in 3D mode. Even if I export in 2D mode it will show up as in 3D mode.

Here is the SVG in question.
[image: Here is the SVG in question.]

I imported it properly, extruded, and ready to go.
As you can see, it looks great.
[image: 2D Shape works fine]

However, when I change it to 3D mode, it shows me this.
[image: Top and bottom missing]

I didn't know if this was an issue or not, but sure enough, it does not look right in-game.
[image: In GMod]

How can I fix this?

Using the Source Tools for Blender, Crowbar and VMTEdit.
Here's a screenshot of my settings.
[image: Settings]

Thanks in advance

EDIT: Even when I export it as a 2d curve, it doesn't work right with GMod. I don't know if it is a Blender issue or GMod issue.

Should I make it a mesh item?

Comment: Why don't you keep it as a 2d curve?

Comment: The object is 3d  (as in having height, depth and width) even is the type of curve us a 2d curve with extrusion. Most likely you need to convert it to mesh anyway to export to other apps.

Comment: Other comments are correct, if the 2D is what you want, use the 2D.  Yes, whenever running into problems with exports, it's always a good idea to alt-c curve to mesh (which also applies modifiers).